# AWS Sagemaker: Can the existing train_image demo be modified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, docker-image, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying a demo "DeepAR-Electricity.ipynb" on AWS Sagemaker.

But after running "estimator.fit" for training, I can only get the log of avg_epoch_loss in every epoch, printed by some functions that I could not find. How can I plot the training and validation loss curves?

Can the existing train_image demo be modified? If no, how to plot the training and validation loss curves? If yes, how to access the source training function?

[image]

Comment: If you want to use a custom trained model, you should use your own docker image with that model with a custon inference code.

Answer (score 0):

As Praneeth pointed out, the container image of DeepAR cannot be modified. If you want to plot the learning curve, one possibility is to parse the log. I have attached an example showing how a log downloaded into 'deepar-log.txt' could be parsed.

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('deepar-log.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = '\n'.join(f.readlines())
    avg_loss_re = re.compile("Epoch\[(\d+)\].*Batch.*\[(\d+)\].*avg_epoch_loss=(-?\d+\.?\d*)")
    avg_losses = [(int(epoch), int(batch), float(loss)) for epoch, batch, loss in avg_loss_re.findall(lines)]
    plt.plot([loss for _, _, loss in avg_losses])
    plt.show()
```